# how can I redraw a circle on an HTML5 canvas in this specific case? (method call versus directly using context object)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a website that is entirely contained within an HTML canvas. The canvas should resize to fit in the browser window at all times, and the elements contained within should resize accordingly.

I'm writing all my JS inside < script >(function() {} )();< /script > so that it runs after the page has loaded.

I declare my canvas and context globally, at the start of the function, like this:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I then have a Circle object, which has the following method:

```
this.drawCircularBackground = function()
{
    context.beginPath()
    //row and col are passed to the constructor, and indicate the position of the circle
    //on a grid within the canvas, making the position relative to canvas dimensions
    context.arc(canvas.width/16*this.col, canvas.height/16*this.row, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
    context.fillStyle = "black"
    context.fill();
}
```

I have a Network object, which contains an array of such circles.

I then have a Page object, which contains an instance of the Network object, and has a resizeCanvas method:

```
this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//only drawing one circle for now, to test
this.network.circles[0].drawCircularBackground();
```

this method is associated with resizing the window by this line, in an initialize() function which is called at the bottom of all this code to start the website .

```
function initialize()
{
   var page = new Page()
    window.addEventListener('resize', page.resizeCanvas, false);
    page.resizeCanvas()
}
```

**so far, this code draws a circle in the upper left corner of the canvas, with a radius of 30. however, when I resize the window, the circle disappears. If I replace this line...**

```
this.network.circles[0].drawCircularBackground();
```

**with the code inside the function called by that line...**

```
//this.network.circles[0].drawCircularBackground();

context.beginPath()
//row and col are passed to the constructor, and indicate the position of the circle
//on a grid within the canvas, making the position relative to canvas dimensions
context.arc(canvas.width/16*this.col, canvas.height/16*this.row, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
context.fillStyle = "black"
context.fill();
```

**the circle remains visible when I resize the window, and changes position relative to the canvas size***

So I'm stumped. Why do the different contexts for drawing the circle produce different results when the window is resized? Can I not call the drawing indirectly within a function that has been associated with the window-resize event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work... I just changed the canvas and context variables to global since I don't know where or how you are storing them. Maybe that's where your problem is.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var Circle = function (col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};
Circle.prototype.drawCircularBackground = function () {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(
    canvas.width/16*this.col, 
    canvas.height/16*this.row, 
    30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false
  );
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fill();
};

var network = {
  circles: [new Circle(1,1)]
};

var Page = function () {};
Page.prototype.resizeCanvas = function () {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  network.circles[0].drawCircularBackground();  
};

var initialize = function () {
   var page = new Page();
   window.addEventListener('resize', page.resizeCanvas, false);
   page.resizeCanvas();
};

initialize();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

playground: http://jsbin.com/dinabasapi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I used your code, and it does work! However, the same problem arises when I make Network an object with a constructor, and initialize circles as this.circles = [new Circle(1,1)] in the constructor. Then, I add an instance of Network to Page in Page's constructor, by saying this.network = new Network(). I now call this.network.circles[0].drawCircularBackground() within resizeCanvas(), and my original problem occurs. The circle disappears when I try to resize the window.

Comment: I can fix it by declaring var network = new Network() just before the line network.circles[0].drawCircularBackground(). So the difference seems to be between using an instance of Network within the function scope, versus an instance of Network that belongs to the object. Why would this make a difference?

Comment: the answer is simple... scopes